# how can I remove permission for logged on user to like/comment on its own post?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I'm trying to make a mini social media API, and want to ensure that the each user can comment and like other posts but can't do that on their own post.

This is the code for my current like system, anyone has an idea of how do i revoke permission to like a post for that one specific user logged on?

```
// LIKE DISLIKE
router.put("/:id/like" ,verifyToken, async(req , res)=>{
    try {
          const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
          if(!post.likes.includes(req.user._id)){
                await post.updateOne({$push:{likes:req.user._id}})
                return res.status(200).json("Post has been liked")
                
          }else{
                await post.updateOne({$pull:{likes:req.user._id}});
                return res.status(200).json("Post has been unliked")
          }
          
    } catch (error) {
     return res.status(500).json(err)     
    }
})
```

I've tried comparing the parameter of the user id (user:req.user._id) to the user ID of the one within the post but that didn't work.

post Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true
    },
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    likes:{
        type:Array,
        deafult:0
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    comments:[
        {
                  user:{
                            type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                            required:true
                  },
                  profile:{
                            type:String
                  },
                  comment:{
                            type:String,
                            required:true
                  },
                  date: {
                    type: Date,
                    default:Date.now
                  }

        }
    ]
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('post',postSchema)
```

Comment: Can you show the `Post` schema definition?

Comment: added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if `user` is equal to `req.user._id` and block the operation in that case.
Also, you should change your `likes` type declaration to an array of `ObjectId` if you want to store user identifiers in there:

```
likes: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  deafult: []
}],
```

Try with this code:

```
router.put('/:id/like', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.user === req.user._id) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'You cannot like your own posts.' })
    }
    if (!post.likes.includes(req.user._id)) {
      post.likes.push(req.user._id);
      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Post has been liked' });
    } else {
      post.likes = [...post.likes].filter(id => id !== req.user._id);
      await post.save();

      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Post has been unliked' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, still can like my own post. Unsure how to check why as console log (post.user) doesnt seem to print anything

Comment: Played with it for a while, your approach did work, so thank you! Off topic: Would you have an idea of how to sort the posts via amount of likes?

Comment: You may wanna use query aggregation and the `$size` operator, for more check https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/